# In MongoDB, is v8 as fast as using a driver

Tags: performance, mongodb

We are testing a load harness and we wrote it as shell scripts calling javascript files via the mongo shell. I just wanted to get your opinion as to whether running the algorithm this way might not give us correct results given that the mongo shell is for admin and relies on a javascript engine. Would running the algorithm written as an app in Java or some other language give us different results?
I guess the short question is will an algorithm that loads mongodb have performance differences when using the shell vs a driver. Also, anything we should keep in mind as we compare MMAP vs WiredTiger in 3.0.7?

Comment: It depends on many factors, I will assume that since you are testing mongodb in general you are using single server (not a distributed sharded/replicated set). There will be some difference in the time taken to traverse a network since you have only a loopback to traverse. There is also likely to be some overhead from Java itself. It would be preferable to benchmark from where your application would be (i.e. i a Java app) since that would give real world results instead of useless bloggable junk

Comment: The second question is too broad and too vague